# 'GtkToggleButton {aka struct _GtkTogglebutton}' has no member 'active'

Tags: c, struct, gtk

I am trying to compile and run an example of `gtk+3`, unfortunately, the example is from gtk+2 manual, I can't find anything useful on `gtk+3` and I can't download `gtk+2`.
On the example there are a couple of function like this:

```
void entry_toggle_editable( GtkWidget *checkbutton,
GtkWidget *entry )
{
    gtk_editable_set_editable(GTK_EDITABLE(entry),GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(checkbutton)->active);
}
```

When compiling I got this error:

```
'GtkToggleButton {aka struct _GtkToggleButton}' has no member named 'active'
```

I looked in all manuals. I was able to find in order to get around the problem, I understand that probably it is a release compatibility problem, but `gtk+3` manuals are really useless for somebody approaching for the first time Gtk.

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest changes between GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3 is that GTK+ 3 gets rid of all public structure fields, replacing them with GObject properties. So instead of saying

```
GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(checkbutton)->active
```

you say

```
gboolean active;
g_object_get(checkbutton, "active", &active, NULL);
```

(The `NULL` is because `g_object_get()` can get multiple properties from the same object at the same time; the `NULL` says "that is all I need from this call".)

GTK+ also provides accessor methods to add type checking, so you can also say

```
gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(checkbutton))
```

Using these when available is preferable to calling `g_object_get()` directly.

The GTK+ documentation does come with [a tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html). As you probably realized, you cannot use GTK+ 2 examples to learn GTK+ 3 without modification; you will need to spend more time finding GTK+ 3 examples.